# Original Transaction Id of Paypal is not storing in database

Tags: paypal

I am using following code to store information in database in php.

```
   if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    @$querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&"; 

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();

 } else{

    // Response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }


    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['userid']         = $_POST['userid'];
    $data['quantity']       = $_POST['quantity'];
    $data['item_name']      = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']         = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']         = $_POST['custom'];


    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {    

        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024); 

                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);


        if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO payments (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, packageID, createdtime,UserID) VALUES (
                '".$_POST['txn_id']."' ,
                '".$_POST['mc_gross']."' ,
                '".$_POST['payment_status']."' ,
                '".$_POST['item_number']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' ,
        '".$userid."' )";
     $paymentQueryResult= mysql_query($sql,$link);              

            if($paymentQueryResult){

                echo "Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the  Database";        
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database          

            }
            else{   
                echo "Payment has been made but not recorded in system database. Please contact administrator ";                            
                        // Error inserting into DB
                        // E-mail admin or alert user

                    }
                }else{  
                    echo "Payment made but data has been changed";              
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user

                }                       

        }       
    fclose ($fp);
    }   
}
```

But in my case the transaction id which displays after transaction from paypal is not same as the transaction id which stores in database by above code. Means in database different transaction id stores or Both transaction ids are different.

I have searched for solution but haven't got success.

Please give me right solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal assigns different transaction ID's to the buyer and seller for a single transaction.  Sounds like you're going through the checkout and seeing a transaction ID on screen, which is what PayPal is presenting to the buyer.  Your IPN solution is receiving the transaction ID they provide the seller.

You should be able to do a search for either transaction ID in your PayPal account to find the transaction details, but again, you're going to see different ID's for the buyer and seller.  This is normal.